# Which blacklists of poor quality scientific journals are run formally by a government agency?

Tags: disreputable-publishers

I read on *Nature News* [China introduces sweeping reforms to crack down on academic misconduct](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05359-8)
 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180609024858/https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05359-8)) 2018-06-08:

> The policy also states that MOST [the Chinese Ministry of Science and Technology] will establish a **blacklist of ‘poor quality’ scientific journals**, including domestic and international titles. Scientists who publish in these journals will receive a warning, and those papers will not be considered in assessments for promotions, jobs and grants. A couple of such [blacklists already exist](https://www.nature.com/news/pay-to-view-blacklist-of-predatory-journals-set-to-launch-1.22090), but **rarely are they run formally by a government agency**.

Which blacklists of poor quality scientific journals are run formally by a government agency (aside from the blacklist created for the policy presented in this news article)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one:

- The Ministry of Education (MOE) of Malaysia have blacklisted (at least) four publishers. I don't know how to find the official source, but the list can be accessed from at least two university websites: [Universiti Utara Malaysia](http://rimc.uum.edu.my/index.php/en/publication/blacklisted-journals-by-moe) and [University Teknologi Malaysia](https://comp.utm.my/sitizaiton/journals-are-not-taken-into-account-in-myra/).